# Time.sleep() command is slower that real time, in python?

Tags: python, time

So, I am working on a project with the RPi, and (with python code), I want it to check something every 0.00001 seconds and note the amount of time taken until the condition is met.

I am using `time.sleep()`, by importing time

If I set that value to 0.001 or more, only then it works, if it's below 0.001 then time becomes either slower or faster,
eg. it takes like 3 seconds to check 1 second...

What can I do? Can you suggest any other way, except for time.sleep?

The following code just says

```
if GPIO 16 on the pi is high,
    then, until GPIO 32 is not high, it will time the time
```

And the loop breaks and code ends when GPIO 32 is high

The first while loop is so the program keeps looping, which I needed it to do, you can ignore

```py
import RPi.GPIO as hello
import time
    
hello.setwarnings(False)
hello.setmode(hello.BOARD)
hello.setup(16, hello.IN)
hello.setup(32, hello.IN)
    
t=0
while 1: 
##Main Code, with the problem...   
    while 1:

        t=0
        if hello.input(16)==1:
            print(t)
            while hello.input(32)==0:
                t=t+0.00001
                time.sleep(0.00001)#Not Working
            if hello.input(32)==1:
                print(t)
                print("Speed=",14/t,"cm/s")
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations to all time critical functions.
I suggest overthinking the use of sleep() and using Timer Objects as stated in the Python Documentary instead.
https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/timer-objects.html

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two things here to note:

1. The argument to `time.sleep()` and the underlying system call is a lower bound. There is no guarantee that the system will not sleep for longer. (In fact we can predict that it will, if typically only by a small amount if system load is light.)
2. The execution of *any* Python code in a nanosecond timeframe is unrealistic on contemporary hardware.

   ```
   >>> import timeit
   >>> timeit.timeit('pass', number=10000)
   8.20159912109e-05
   ```